# Load only first frame of Video

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, video-streaming

I was just wondering if it is possible to just load the first frame of a video in AS3, so I can use it as a screenshot/preview type of thing?

Thanks in advance :)
Harry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Load only the first frame wouldn't be possible without starting the process to load all video, then, it would take a little while to show the image and pause the video before playing.
Some CDNs provide an image url, if isn't your case, you could use [FFMPEG](http://flowplayer.org/tutorials/generating-thumbs.html) to generate your thumbs.